# Reputation how to get Stackexchange vote rights

Tags: discussion, reputation, votes

I want to upvote the second answer as it is better [Turning Google Timeline into a travel map](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/97919/turning-google-timeline-into-a-travel-map)
but for some reason new users or anyone with low reputation (But who has been using stackoverflow for 10 years) does not count, and I have no clue how to get reputation needed to fix the broken internet (nope the V1.0 bits of internet.) I've been on here for ages and have always wanted to upvote, but am unable to so it's now reached the frustration point - yes I am aware I need to contribute, but my specialty is not represented here at all.

Comment: Thanks @marikamitsos , I'm not complaining per se'. I use all of these linked communities, but have to adopt a fresh persona, or my questions/need means I have a different use-case that often is not met by the specific community. SO is my home, SE is my second home but the other sites are places I am not safe at all. I have a bad habit of trying to fix broken pieces of the web, and of fighting battles that cannot be won.

Comment: @Rubén _"...could look like be helping the OP"_. I believe our mutual explanations leave no space to anyone to even remotely think that. Nevertheless, taking into account a very remote possibility of such a thought one should only read my answer and my prompting to move this post to Meta (where it should be). And in any case, I am the one who [flagged the question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/117311) to be moved.

Answer (score 2):

*I have no clue how to get reputation needed*

*yes I am aware I need to contribute, but my specialty is not represented here at all*

Your question is not about reputation for commenting, specifically, but these two meta posts apply:

[How does a lurker gain reputation to receive privilege for commenting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164035/how-does-a-lurker-gain-reputation-to-receive-privilege-for-commenting)

Among other things this specifically adresses the *specialty* issue:

> - You could do that by correcting the grammar of either questions or answers
> - Asking sensible questions that interest others is worth pursuing
> - If you have more than 10 reputation, you can also get a lot of reputation from editing by changing links to images in posts by new users.

The above post also links to:

[Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: Why would I want to edit peoples posts? surely I need reputation before I can do that? My original point stands, I intend no evil, yet the community has an unconscious bias toward high value questions which are focused around their core topics only; which is fair enough, but shows the problem up.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't say you are complaining. I just stated my awareness of the fact that:

**In order to protect the voting system (people registering just to give fake upvotes) we end up with this "flaw/defect"**.

I hope your question gets enough attention (2 more upvotes) so you can cast your vote as well. As an alternative you could use [meta](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-posts) (*"Privilege type: Creation privilege **Awarded at: 1 reputation**.... available to everyone, regardless of reputation level"*) to [post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) your concern.

Also, keep in mind that once you get 200 points at any site you get awarded 100 points ***"Association Bonus"*** to the other sites as stated here at an [early post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/08/cross-site-account-associations/).

Answer (score 1):

**Tl;Dr:** Earn 200 reputation score on one of the sites were you are able to contribute valuable content to gain the 100 association bonus, then when you join a new site like this, will will start from 100 reputation, instead of 1. This is also applied on sites that you are already joined.

---

I'm very glad to know that you found something helpful and that you want to upvote it. We really need more people upvoting good on-topic content (related help article [Why is voting important](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)) and more people *fighting the good fight*.

Based on the the way that this site is intended to work, new users should start by searching for interesting content and if they didn't find what they are looking for, then do an **on-topic and helpful** post, it even could be a self answered question (related help article [How do I ask a good question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask))

<sup>NOTE: There is no need to create an account for this but it's recommended (related help article  [Why should I create an account](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-register))</sup>.

Then the users will gain reputation and at certain reputation they will gain privileges, one of these privileges is to up-vote (related help articles [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) and [Vote up](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up))). Earning **15 reputation score** it's not so hard if you really are committed to earn them, but on this site it could require to be a bit patient specially on tags that haven't many active voters.

Another privilege is the **100 reputation association bonus**. It requires to have 200 reputation points on one Stack Exchange site.

If the user needs help about how the site works, it's expected that the user first go to the help center and if they need more help then ask on Meta ( related help article [What if I need more help](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/more-help)).

When a new user post a question about how the site works on the main site it eventually could be migrated to Meta (it depends on votes to close as off-topic because it belongs to another site). I think that the reputation gained on this question will be lost as Meta posts doesn't give reputation.

Related

- [Someone's answer was the solution to a problem, too bad I can't tell the community and expand on it](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3777/88163)

Comment: This does explain it all a lot better. It's just quite bizarre that a person asking a question, is unable to upvote any correct answers until they are at 15. In one case I was unable to even comment on answers, which simply means that First time users are discouraged from staying unless they have staying power or a reason to stay. I shall definitely go out there and write up a few questions that only I know the answer to, to eventually progress at last.